# why did it cause a "mutating method sent to immutable object" exception?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have just started to jump into the realm of iOS. I followed an example in the book and an error is thrown out when I ran it:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

the example code listed below:

```
@interface MyXMLElement : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *text;
@property (weak, nonatomic) MyXMLElement *parent;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *children;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *attributes;

@end
```

============================================

```
@implementation MyXMLElement

@synthesize name = _name;
@synthesize text = _text;
@synthesize parent = _parent;
@synthesize children = _children;
@synthesize attributes = _attributes;

-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if(self != nil){
        NSMutableArray *childrenArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        self.children = [childrenArray mutableCopy];
        NSMutableDictionary *attributesDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        self.attributes = [attributesDictionary mutableCopy];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

============================================

```
@interface MyXMLDocument : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *documentPath;
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyXMLElement *rootElement;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSXMLParser *xmlParser;
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyXMLElement *currentElement;

-(BOOL)parseLocalXMLWithPath:(NSString *)paramLocalXMLPath;
@end
```

============================================

```
@implementation MyXMLDocument

@synthesize documentPath = _documentPath;
@synthesize rootElement = _rootElement;
@synthesize xmlParser = _xmlParser;
@synthesize currentElement = _currentElement;

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if (self.rootElement == nil){
        MyXMLElement *root = [[MyXMLElement alloc] init];
        self.rootElement = root; 
        self.currentElement = root;
    } else {
        MyXMLElement *newElement = [[MyXMLElement alloc] init];
        newElement.parent = self.currentElement;
        [self.currentElement.children addObject:newElement];
        self.currentElement = newElement;
    }
    self.currentElement.name = elementName;
    if ([attributeDict count] > 0){
        //this line will throw out a exception.
        [self.currentElement.attributes addEntriesFromDictionary:attributeDict];
    }
}
```

Comment: In wich line the error is thrown?

Answer (score 2):

```
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *attributes;
```

This means that the synthesized method `-[MyXMLElement setAttributes:]` will make a copy of its argument, using the `-copy` method. That produces an immutable object, even when the argument is mutable.

Try changing that to:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *attributes;
```

Also: This code is overcomplicated and leaky.

```
NSMutableDictionary *attributesDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
self.attributes = [attributesDictionary mutableCopy];
```

Should be:

```
self.attributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

What book is this? It's terrible.

Comment: Thank you for your help, this bug has been fixed but i get a new one:Error Domain=NSXMLParserErrorDomain Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 5.)"

Comment: the xml file content is very simple:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <parent name="vincent">
    </parent>
</xml>

Comment: There is a format error at the end in the xml file,this book is really terrible.

Comment: ha! I had the exact same problem with the exact same code. The book is 
http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9781449398002



iOS 4 Programming Cookbook
By: Vandad Nahavandipoor
Publisher: O'Reilly Media, Inc.
Pub. Date: February 1, 2011
Print ISBN-13: 978-1-4493-8822-5
Pages in Print Edition: 640
Download Book [15 Tokens]: PDF, Mobi, ePub
Subscriber Rating:  [7 Ratings] Subscriber Reviews